# Need to migrate a CakePhp application from php 5 to 7 in AWS Centos

Tags: amazon-web-services, cakephp, centos, php-7

I need to move a cakePhp Application from php 5 to 7 in a AWS instance.

I have created a new AWS Centos instance and installed php 7 on it. Then I moved all the files from original server to the new server. 
I have tried to upgrade CakePhp to latest version. (Through shell, from the logs Everything was updated successfully except Version.txt file and licensce.txt File.

I am not able to access my application through New change.

Error while accessing the application: http://34.210.73.74/util/index.php
Host Not Found
DNS error (the host name of the page you are looking for does not exist) or Server did not accept the connection.

Comment: As the error message clearly states this is a DNS problem. It has very likely nothing to do with php at all.

Comment: Agree to burzum: Try to look up your DNS entry and set the DocumentRoot and Directory Directive in your VirtualHost to the correct path of your cakephp app.

Comment: The CakePHP 1.3 to 2.x upgrade tool is not great, many things changed. Have you tried doing this locally first to see if the app still runs after running the update tool?

Comment: @Erebus Hi I tried updating the cakephp . Basically replacing the old cakePhp folder with upgraded one. But I stil get can't get it working. The old one gives error as "Fatal error: Cannot use 'String' as class name as it is reserved in /var/www/html/lib/Cake/Utility/String.php on line 26".The new one can't even load the application.